# Connection to postgres running in docker fails using go gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to connect to postgres running in a docker container from another container using gorm but I am getting

> panic: failed to connect to `host=postgres user=postgres database=test`: dial error (dial tcp 192.168.176.5:6543: connect: connection refused)

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  patients-service:
    build:
      context: ./../patients-service
      dockerfile: ./../patients-service/patients-service.dockerfile
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.2'
    ports:
      - "6543:5432"
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    volumes:
      - ./db-data/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Here is my go file:

```
package database

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "log"
)

var DB *gorm.DB
var err error

func Open() error {

    dsn := "host=postgres port=6543 user=postgres password=password dbname=test sslmode=disable timezone=UTC connect_timeout=5"
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The weird thing is if I use port 5432 instead of 6543 in my code and change port mapping in docker-compose to `- "5432:5432"` it will connect just fine but I have postgres running locally and I don't want the two to interfere with each other since I am planning to connect to the one running in docker in DBeaver and localhost:5432 obviously connects to the local one.

Comment: Connections between containers don't use port mapping -- you must connect to the port on which postgres is listening (5432).  Additionally, postgres takes a few seconds to start up. If you application attempts to connect immediately it may fail; you need to include logic to retry the connection until it succeeds.